# Is the Rails console running as a Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It seems like Rails' console (`script/console` or `rails console`) is like in a controller, but `self.class` gives `Object` (Rails 3.0.1 with Ruby 1.9.2), so is it controller or none of M, V, or C?

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing - as it's not part of your production stack, but just a tool that sets up a useful debugging environment for you.

And it's certainly not a part of your application, so it doesn't fit into the whole MVC model.

Comment: As stated above it's not in the context of either a model, controller or view. It simply loads the classes in your app, so that your models etc, are available to call methods on, if you want to get your hand dirty and see what's going on in any of those parts of your app, you should try setting up a breakpoint and use `ruby-debug` to see what's available at each scope.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-1-security/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb

You can see it basically just parses command-line options and then starts an IRB session. Helper methods like "reload!" are defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-1-security/railties/lib/rails/console/app.rb).